# Can I read programmed content inside any sort of non-volatile re-programmable memory device with Microscope, X-ray, etc.?

Tags: flash, nand, non-volatile-memory, x-rays, microscope

Non-volatile re-programmable memory like NAND flash, NOR flash, and etc. stores information in forms of electron charges and doesn't change in structural forms that can be inspected with X-ray or Microscope.

Then is there a way to inspect content of the memory when it cannot be addressed with normal way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the package is opened and the actual chip exposed, the memory contents can be read using a scanning electron microscope (SEM). See [this paper](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~sps32/cardis2016_sem.pdf) for example.